# How can I make a half-half layout with some text using display: flex?

Tags: css

I want to make a half-half layout. So I made a `<div>` that had `display: flex;` and put two children that had `flex-grow: 1;`. It looked like what I expected, a half-half layout. But when I put something in one of the children, it got larger than the other.

I can’t quite grasp why it works this way.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOvpPM

Could you please tell me the why and the proper CSS for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flexbox works that way. If you have two elements (or any amount of elements) in a flex-box, and give them all the same `flex-grow`, they will all 'grow' the same amount.

If you have a parent flex container with a width of 300px, with two children; one with a width of 0px, and another with 100px, both will grow an additional 100px, resulting in a 100px and a 200px div.

If you want them both to be 50% of the width, just add

```
width: 50%;
```

and remove

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

from the CSS.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

As already mentioned by Gust, the initial width is also important. If you haven't specified it, it's calculated by the content. This is the so called flex-basis.

So you need to define the flex-basis, for example:

```
.half {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If you just use the shorthand property

```
.half {
  flex: 1;
}
```

it will also set the flex-basis to 0, so the space get's seperated evenly.
A good source for more information is [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/).

Answer (score 1):

A pure flexbox **Solution** is just:

```
flex: 1
```

**The Problem**

flex: 1 is a shorthand to set flex-grow to 1, BUT they are not the same.

`flex: 1` means:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0;// !!!
```

When using `flex-grow: 1`

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;// oops !!!
```

`flex-basis: auto` - If an item has a width set the size will be based on that width.
In your case by writing to your `<span>` you are actually expanding your first `<div class="half">`

`flex-basis 0` - The item size is not taken into consideration for the space-sharing calculation.
In your case the first and second `<div>` will have equal width regardless of their actual size.

To see the difference set your width to an absolute (fixed) value:

```
.flexContatiner
{
  width: 500px;
}
```

Best documentation on these topics can be found here:

[Controlling ratios of flex items along the main axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax)

To see more detailed answers from other Devs on `flex-1` and `flex-grow` see below links:

[The difference between flex:1 and flex-grow:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767405/the-difference-between-flex1-and-flex-grow1)

To me this one was the best explained/illustrated!

[Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520932/make-flex-grow-expand-items-based-on-their-original-size)